# How to get packagename of runningtask on Android M5.1.1

Tags: deprecated, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm new to Android and i'm trying to make a project that allows user to see which applications are running. I used this code to get the packagename of the running task on top:

> ```
>            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
>                 List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningappInfo = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
>                 for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo app : runningappInfo) {
>                     if (app.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && app.importanceReasonCode == 0) {
>                         Integer state = null;
>                         try {
>                             state = field.getInt(app);
>                         } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
>                             e.printStackTrace();
>                         }
>                         if (state != null && state == PROCESS_STATE_TOP) {
>                             currentInfo = app;
>                             break;
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>                if (currentInfo != null) {
>                     current = currentInfo.processName.split(":")[0];
>                 }
>            }else{
>                 List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfos = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
>                 ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfos.get(0).topActivity;
>                 current = componentInfo.getPackageName();
>            }
> ```

`current` here is packagename of the runningtask. But this code didn't work any more after Google update the new android version Lollipop5.1.1. The method "getRunningAppProcesses" now returns a list null.
I get stuck now because all other functions in my project work only if I can get the runningtask's packagename. If anybody has resolved this kind of problem, Could you please help me?
Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2347

Android suggests to use this for finding top application.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html